# Get ENCODING_ERR while trying to read file from cordova.file.dataDirectory

Tags: android, cordova-plugins

I get an `ENCODING_ERR` error code (code 5) when I try to read a file from `cordova.file.dataDirectory`

```
var filename = "settings.dat";           
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + filename, function(f){
                f.file(function(file){
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(){
                        var data = this.result;
                        alert("ok");
                    };
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                }, function(res){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(res));
                });
            }, function(res){
                alert(JSON.stringify(res));
            });
```

I have no idea why. I tried checking the permission and I have it. The URL is also well formed

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? I have the same problem